# using the arm template to copy the App Logic

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

using the arm template to copy the App Logic from Resource group A to Resource group B
it always say connection API is missing or wrong (wHEN i COPY RESOURCE GROUP A logic App workflow template to resource group B-->it says cannot save due to invalid connection API)
How can I fix the connection API in ARM template in the new Resource group B?

Comment: - Instead of copying the code view from logic app1 to logic app2. 
- You can use the `clone` option to create a copy of the same logic app in the same resource group A then perform the `logicapp` move operation from resource group A to resource group B.

Comment: You can refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/move-logic-app-resources) documentation, for more information about resource move in logic apps.
You can also refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67804450/how-to-create-standard-type-logic-apps-using-arm-templates) thread.